# Getting error on await act() JEST. Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I am new to unit testing and jest, and was stuck at a scenario where the react's state are being set asynchronously after API call is resolved or rejected. I found some answers in which they've mentioned to use `waitFor` or `await act(async()=>{})`. Whenever I'm trying to await with act or even async act, I'm getting this error and the tests are failing. I've tried to replicate a similar scenario below.
If these ways of handling async updates to component are not correct, then what could be the other solutions. I'm using react hooks to set the state after api resolves or rejects.

**React and react-dom version : 16.8**

```
test('new ', async () => {
  await act(() => {
    console.log('test');
  });
  expect('temp').toBe('temp');
});
```

Comment: Didn't see react component. What are you testing? Show the code

Comment: If we just have that above snippet in test file, it works well with react-dom >= 16.9, but fails with 16.8, giving the mentioned error. 

Component:
`const handleApi = () => {
 const result = await fetch(some address);
 setData(result);
}`
and on buttonClick this function was called
```<button onClick = {handleApi}>Button</button>```

and I was simulating click using enzyme wrapped in `act()` block. But there are async updates happening in the component, so to handle that, I thought of using `waitFor`, or `async(act())`, but both of them give error with react 16.8